# CSV File Adding New ROW After Every ROW

Tags: csv

When I am trying to copy a CSV file from server one to server two the csv file adding a new row after every every row.

Example:

```
   ORIGINAL FILE:
   1. ONE
   2. TWO
   3. THREE
   4. FOUR



  AFTER TRANSFERRING THE FILE:    
   1. ONE
   2. 
   3. TWO
   4.
   5. THREE
   6.
   7. FOUR
```

i am running this system for there months. And this problem happened suddenly. And this is problem is not regular. this is the 2nd time i am facing this problem.

I am using Filezilla to upload the file. After upload the file, with a script i am scanning the directory for csv file  after every 2 minutes. then move the csv file to another server.

Need help

Comment: How are you copying the CSV file?

Comment: i am using simple linux copy command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem just could be that you are not transferring in binary mode. You want to be in binary mode or it can cause different formatting.

> After you log in to an ftp site, ftp will print out the file transfer
>   type. In our case, it is binary. Binary mode transfers the files, bit
>   by bit, as they are on the FTP server. Ascii mode, however, will
>   download the text directly. You can type `ascii` or `binary` to switch
>   between the types.

Source: http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/FTP-3.html

Comment: Did the binary option fix it? Or was it something else?

Comment: i am not so sure. because i didn't do anything with my coding. but it is still running with my simple copy command code.